# App works on real phones but no longer on emulator

Tags: android

My app works on two different phones, but it no longer works on the emulator. I immediately get the stopped unexpectedly error on the emulator. I have rebooted my computer, and it did not change things. I am at wits end!

The debugger shows this:

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
    ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2663  
    ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2679   
    ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 125 
    ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 2033  
    ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
    Looper.loop() line: 123 
    ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4627    
    Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521  
    ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 868  
    ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 626 
    NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Comment: Are you using NDK and JNI ? If yes, were you using it before this problem started occurring ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem, it had nothing to do with phone vs. emulator. I thought I was using logcat correctly but I was not. Thanks to a suggestion I tried again and it lead me to my problem.